# Symfony - call Doctrine in cron tab

Tags: php, symfony, cron

Hey guys i want to know how can i do a cron tab but that cron tab has to update database so i need

> $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()

But for this i need to extend `Controller` but i already extend `Command`

So i there a way to extend both ? Do i have to use sql commands ?Or an other way to update the database with cron tab ?

Here you can find my find and see what i need :

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class MessageController extends Command
{
    protected function configure () {
        $this->setName('app:notification');
        $this->setDescription("Permet juste d'envoyer les notifications");
        $this->setHelp("Je serai affiche si on lance la commande app/console app:notification -h");
    }

    public function execute (InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
        //HERE I WANT TO DO : $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $output->writeln('!');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can extend ContainerAwareCommand instead and use

```
$this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager()
```

Comment: i think that works thx :) i can't accept the response for 9min so wait a bit a i put it to valid

Comment: thx a lot men :)

Comment: Avoid using the container directly in Symfony 4: Better inject the doctrine registry into the constructor via DIC.